# Does elisp have a way to jump to (goto) labels in the code, ala common lisp's go?

Tags: elisp, common-lisp, cl

Does elisp have a way to jump to (goto) labels in the code, ala common lisp's [go](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_go.htm)?

```
 (tagbody
   (setq val 2)
   (go lp)
   (incf val 3)
   lp (incf val 4)) =>  NIL
 val =>  6
```

PS: This is a question about control flow, not jumping to locations in files.

Comment: The `cl-lib` library offers `cl-tagbody` (and, I presume, friends), which offers some of the common lisp primitives to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @Dan Thanks, that's the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It works exactly the same, we just need to use `cl-tagbody` instead.

```
(cl-tagbody
 (setq val 2)
 (go lp)
 (incf val 3)
 lp (incf val 4))

val
```

```
6
```